# Swift Class members in TableView

Tags: swift, tableview

I'm building an app that displays various data into a tableView.

I want to create variables that inherit from a class and display them in a tableView.

This is my class file :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class Shops {
    private var _shopName: String!
    private var _shopOpeningWD: String!
    private var _shopOpeningSat: String!
    private var _shopOpeningSun: String!
    private var _shopLogo: UIImage!

    init(shopName: String , shopOpeningWD: String ,shopOpeningSat: String,shopOpeningSun: String, shopLogo: UIImage ) {
    self._shopName = shopName
    self._shopOpeningWD = shopOpeningWD
    self._shopOpeningSat = shopOpeningSat
    self._shopOpeningSun = shopOpeningSun
    }   
}
```

This it the file i want to get the data from :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

var amazon = Shops(shopName: "amazon", shopOpeningWD: "Monday - Friday : 9:00 - 21:00", shopOpeningSat: "Saturday: 10:30 - 20:00", shopOpeningSun: "Sunday: 10:30 - 15:00 ", shopLogo:UIImage(named: "shopLogo")!)

var pcParts = Shops(shopName: "pcParts", shopOpeningWD: "Monday - Friday : 9:00 - 20:00", shopOpeningSat: "Saturday: 10:30 - 20:00", shopOpeningSun: "Sunday: 10:30 - 15:00 ", shopLogo: UIImage(named: "shopLogo")!)

var newEgg = Shops(shopName: "newEgg", shopOpeningWD: "Monday - Friday: 9:00 - 21:00", shopOpeningSat: "Saturday: 10:30 - 20:00", shopOpeningSun: "Sunday: 10:30 - 15:00 ", shopLogo: UIImage(named: "shopLogo")!)
```

This is a function i created in viewController ( where the tableView is located)

```
func populateArray() -> Array <Shops> {

    var array = [Shops]()

    array.append(amazon)
    array.append(pcParts)
    array.append(newegg)

    return array
}
```

The function is called in viewDidLoad.
I created a variable that grabs the value of the array

```
var newArray : [Shops] {

    return populateArray()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return  newArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tabel.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

cell.shopName =
```

How can i get the class variables into the cellForRowAtIndexPath function ?
I don't get autocomplete when i try to write cell.shopName = newArray.shopName ...

Thanks in advance.
As you can see, I'm trying to learn so have mercy :)

Managed to solve the issue :

I didn't get the value from the private variables :

I added this to my Class file.

```
var shopName: String {
    return _shopName
}

var shopOpeningWD: String {
    return _shopOpeningWD
}

var shopOpeningSat: String {
    return _shopOpeningSat
}

var shopOpeningSun : String {
    return _shopOpeningSun
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
let item = newArray[indexPath.row]
print("\(item._shopName)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place these variables into a Class.

```
class HoursHandler: NSObject {

var amazon = Shops(shopName: "amazon", shopOpeningWD: "Monday - Friday : 9:00 - 21:00", shopOpeningSat: "Saturday: 10:30 - 20:00", shopOpeningSun: "Sunday: 10:30 - 15:00 ", shopLogo:UIImage(named: "shopLogo")!)
var pcParts = Shops(shopName: "pcParts", shopOpeningWD: "Monday - Friday : 9:00 - 20:00", shopOpeningSat: "Saturday: 10:30 - 20:00", shopOpeningSun: "Sunday: 10:30 - 15:00 ", shopLogo: UIImage(named: "shopLogo")!)
var newEgg = Shops(shopName: "newEgg", shopOpeningWD: "Monday - Friday: 9:00 - 21:00", shopOpeningSat: "Saturday: 10:30 - 20:00", shopOpeningSun: "Sunday: 10:30 - 15:00 ", shopLogo: UIImage(named: "shopLogo")!)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use private backed variables as an *alibi* for read-only properties.

Use **constants**:

```
class Shops {
    let shopName: String
    let shopOpeningWD: String
    let shopOpeningSat: String
    let shopOpeningSun: String
    let shopLogo: UIImage

    init(shopName: String , shopOpeningWD: String ,shopOpeningSat: String,shopOpeningSun: String, shopLogo: UIImage ) {
      self.shopName = shopName
      self.shopOpeningWD = shopOpeningWD
      self.shopOpeningSat = shopOpeningSat
      self.shopOpeningSun = shopOpeningSun
      self.shopLogo = shopLogo
    }   
}
```